# Angular: How start the App later?

Tags: angular

I look a way to start an Angular 4 App later, not during page loading but when a button on webpage is clicked for instance. How can I do?

My app is integrated to a standard HTML page, rendered by PHP server and the goal is to be able start the Angular App when the button is clicked.

I found this one [Activating Angular JS on an already loaded non-Angular webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585110/activating-angular-js-on-an-already-loaded-non-angular-webpage) but I don't know how adapt it for Angular 4.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should try lazy loading in your angular application. [Info](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: Thank you Ryan for you answer but lazy loading is to handle multiple routes in angular App, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution that fits my needs.

In fact, I move the code of `ngAfterViewInit()` in public method `load()`. Angular App is started without the content is loaded.

In the constructor, I set the global variable `MyApp = this`.

In the HTML page, where Angular App and other page contents are rendered, I implement a button where the `MyApp.load()` is called.

This implementation works fine.